# Making SSIS package accesible to other user on the system

Tags: sql

I have a package to perform a simple task of downloading a file from an FTP and uploading to other.
How do I make a package executable by other logins on the same system. When I try to execute the package using other logins, I get an error stating that it cannot use the password.... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You will need a windows account with permission to execute the package and access everything the package needs to touch (file share permission, FTP permissions, run exec files, database permissions, folder permissions etc..).  You also want to make sure that login is a member of the ssis operator and user roles in msdb.

Comment: Very very thanx for the response.....But as I am a new bee... I don't understand the last point ' You also want to make sure that login is a member of the ssis operator and user roles in msdb.
'....How do i do this? Appreciate your help

Comment: Under the security folder in SSMS double-click the login and go to the the user mapping tab.  If you look at the msdb database here you will see those roles.  Grant each of the roles to the account/group that you want the ability to run the package.